# Como calcular a data atual e a data futuro e receber a diferença em dias

Tags: angular, typescript, data, momentjs

Estou utilizando Moment.js para fazer cálculos de data, pensando nisso fiz essa função abaixo para fazer o cálculo da data atual com a data de nascimento:

```
onCalcularData(date: any): number {
    return moment().diff(date, 'years');
}
```

No entanto, estou querendo fazer a mesma coisa que fiz na função acima, porém agora quero calcular a diferença em dias, por exemplo:

22/06/2020 - 26/06/2020 = 4

Tentei fazer utilizando a função "subtrair" mas não consegui.

Comment: tenta  date.diff(moment(), 'years');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se quer a diferença em dias, basta mudar para `moment().diff(date, 'days')`.

Já sobre "calcular para frente e não para trás", você quer dizer que, em vez de calcular `data_atual - date`, você quer `date - data_atual`?

Se for isso, bastaria inverter o sinal:

```
onCalcularData(date: any): number {
    return -moment().diff(date, 'days');
}
```

Coloquei o sinal de menos (`-`), o que "inverte" o retorno. Afinal, se o `date` representar, por exemplo, uma data 10 dias antes da data atual, a diferença entre elas em dias será sempre 10, e a única coisa que muda ao inverter a ordem em que a subtração é feita será o sinal.

---

Claro que você também pode inverter as datas no cálculo:

```
onCalcularData(date: any): number {
    return moment(date).diff(moment(), 'days');
}
```

A diferença é que eu tive que fazer `moment(date)`, pois `date` foi declarado como `any` (ou seja, pode ser "qualquer coisa"), então não necessariamente será um `moment`. Ao fazer `moment(date)`, eu garanto que ela será convertida para um `moment` e posso usar o método `diff`.

No seu código isso não foi necessário porque [segundo a documentação](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/), o método `diff` aceita "qualquer coisa" como parâmetro (um `moment`, uma `string`, um [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), etc) e internamente ele o converte para `moment`, por isso você pode passar o `date` diretamente para `diff`. Mas se quiser "inverter", será necessário transformá-lo em um `moment`.

---

Outra alternativa, se você quiser **apenas** a quantidade de dias entre as datas, independente de uma data estar no futuro ou passado com relação à outra, pode fazer também:

```
onCalcularData(date: any): number {
    return Math.abs(moment().diff(date, 'days'))
}
```

Assim, tanto faz se o resultado é um número positivo ou negativo, a função retorna a quantidade de dias entre as duas datas sem o sinal (tanto faz se a diferença der -10 ou 10, a função retornará 10).

Mas se o sinal for importante, você deve escolher a ordem que fizer mais sentido para o seu caso, e não usar [`Math.abs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs).

---

Mas há um detalhe aí. O cálculo também leva em conta o horário, e a diferença em dias é arredondada para baixo (por exemplo, entre 10h de hoje e 9h de amanhã, a diferença é de zero dias - somente a partir das 10h de amanhã é que a diferença dá 1). E a data atual (`moment()`) sempre terá o horário de quando ela foi criada.

Uma maneira de ignorar o horário é setar ambas as datas para o mesmo horário. Uma alternativa é usar [`startOf('day')`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/) para setá-las para o início do dia:

```
onCalcularData(date: any): number {
    return Math.abs(moment().startOf('day').diff(moment(date).startOf('day'), 'days'));
}
```

Comment: perdão pelo texto confuso, sobre sua sugestao de codigo "moment().diff(date, 'days')", estou a pensar se encaixaria. O que quero fazer é: hoje é dia 22 e no meu campo data, coloco dia 26- quero calcular essa diferença, ou seja 4 dias

Comment: @fernanda Então é só combinar as 2 sugestões, inverter as datas e mudar para dias: `moment(date).diff(moment(), 'days')`

Comment: @fernanda Atualizei a resposta com essa opção

Comment: @hjotsubo, fiz desta forma, porem ele não me traz um calculo exato. Ele pegou a data atual, mais a data prevista e me deu os dias entre uma data e outra, exemplo: 22/06 - 24/06 = 1. Eu gostaria que ele me retornasse 22/06 - 24/06 = 2 ou 3

Comment: @fernanda Atualizei de novo a resposta

Comment: acho que entendi, muito obrigada